# Mysql query to get next id when table is empty

Tags: mysql

I need to get next id in the database table so I perform this query

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) + 1 AS nextId FROM `students`;
```

and it works, but not while the table is empty, if the table is empty it returns "NULL", so can anyone help me with this please
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be using MySQL autoincrement ids rather than praying that you never get more than one user accessing your system at a time

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  `id` should be declared as `auto_increment`, so you don't have to fiddle with the values.

Comment: I'm using transaction, and I'll need it later not just in this @Mark Baker

Comment: I'll need it in not auto increment field @gordon Linoff

Comment: You should __still__ be using autoincrement ids..... this is what they're there for.... generations of database developers figured this out many years ago, and provided autoincrement for precisely this purpose.... and incredibly, they figured out a way of working when there were no records already in the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ISNULL function:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(`id`),0) + 1 AS nextId FROM `students`;
```

But maybe you should have a look at AUTO_INCREMENT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

In MySql the function is called IFNULL()

Comment: It gave me this  "#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'"

Comment: @MohamedSalah In MySQL I think this is IFNULL().

Answer (score 2):

Add conditions. Use `IF` and `ISNULL` together.

```
SELECT IF(ISNULL(id), 1, MAX(`id`) + 1) AS nextId FROM `students`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your answer, but as everyone suggested, you should be using autoincrement

```
    select 
    (
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(`id`) <= 0 THEN 1
        WHEN COUNT(`id`) > 0  THEN MAX(id)
    END) AS nextId
 from students;
```

Comment: really I appreciate your great answer, it's really perfect.